# Regex Too Complicated - replaceAll - large strings preprocessed before deserialize

Tags: apex

**Given**

- A JSON string with Apex reserved words (like `"currency":"USD"` and otherwise undeserializable-into-Date type (like `"someDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"` )
- An apex method that uses

  ```
  String s = s.replaceAll('"currency":','"currencyX":')
              .replaceAll('"0001\\-01\\-01T00:00:00Z"','null');
  ```

before deserializing into a custom Apex type with property `String currencyX` and `Date someDate`

**When**

The incoming Apex string is very large (> 1MB)

**Then**

Uncatchable error: `Regex Too Complicated`

> What to do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is basically teaching an old dog (me) new tricks

A cursory reading of the [Apex String class documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) shows two methods

- `replace(target,replacement)`
- `replaceAll(regExp,replacement)`

The naive developer (me) assumes that the first method, `replace`, only replaces a SINGLE instance of the target string and since the use case assumes you need to replace ALL occurrences of some pattern, you should use the more powerful `replaceAll(..)`

But epistemic arrogance crept in and I did not realize `replace(target,replacement)` replaces ALL occurrences of `target` with `replacement`

> Replaces each substring of a string that matches the literal target sequence target with the specified literal replacement sequence replacement.

So, if you have large strings and you are just doing simple text substitution, avoid `replaceAll`

```
String s = s.replace('"currency":','"currencyX":')
                .replace('"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"','null');
```

Comment: thx for updating your reply for those of us old farts thinking the exact same thing..

Comment: That's not on you, that's on salesforce. They could have easily had the same method name for both methods where the regex version is just an override.

Comment: @TemporaryFix - I think the apex methods are just [borrowed/mimicked from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-string-replace-and-replaceall)

Comment: This answer is probably better: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321918/salesforce-apex-regex-too-complicated-error